# Upvotes and the reputation are not in sync

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page, achievements-dialog

I asked a question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768845/webservice-call-from-android-device-is-not-working-works-well-on-emulator).This question got upvoted by four users(as you can see) but my overall reputation is increased by just 15.
As far as I know,each upvote on a question will give me 5 reputation points.

- My Reputation at the time when i posted this question was 2494(it must be 2514 now)
- The top bar is showing wrong reputation count
- The reputation point count on that question on my profile is correct.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current [reputation log](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681929/nobalg?tab=reputation) shows just +15:

> [image]

I guess someone cancelled their up-vote.

Note that your question got [3 upvotes today](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29768845/timeline); the 4th upvote was given much earlier (on the 21st).

Your summary page then shows you the total for the most recent 24 reputation change events, or fewer if there are more than 4 posts involved. All 4 upvotes on the question are within the last 24 events, so that total of +20 is correct too. Only the -50 for the bounty isn't listed in that summary; it is listed in the *Offered bounty* section of the summary page instead.

[image]

Comment: @mmking: yes, 3 votes today, and the other one 9 days ago.

Comment: my bad,you are right,I added the screenshot,(the green one)